# React failing to render in simple starter setup (React beginner)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello world doesn't render in the browser. Console says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I tried to load the js with type="test/javascript" instead without success.

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<h1>Hello, world</h1>);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
    <title>React</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Modern SPA like react, vue or angular, require some sort of compiling. Since you are new, please make use of create-react-app to create a new project and try.  https://create-react-app.dev/

Comment: I am just trying to get this to work: https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project. Shouldn't have to create-react-app.dev for this.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

react

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';


ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('app')
).render(<h1>Hello World</h1>);
```

Here is a playground:

https://playcode.io/1513128